# Issue with usages of `transform` vs. `fit_transform` in CountVectorizer

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn, countvectorizer

I have successfully trained and tested a Logistic Regression model with `CountVectorizer()` as such:

```
def train_model(classifier, feature_vector_train, label):
    # fit the training dataset on the classifier
    classifier.fit(feature_vector_train, label)

    return classifier

def getPredictions (classifier, feature_vector_valid):    
    # predict the labels on validation dataset
    predict = classifier.predict(feature_vector_valid)

    return metrics.accuracy_score(predict, valid_y)

def createTrainingAndValidation(column):
    global train_x, valid_x, train_y, valid_y
    train_x, valid_x, train_y, valid_y = model_selection.train_test_split(finalDF[column], finalDF['DeedType1'])

def createCountVectorizer(column):
    global xtrain_count, xvalid_count
    # create a count vectorizer object 
    count_vect = CountVectorizer()
    count_vect.fit(finalDF[column])

    # transform the training and validation data using count vectorizer object
    xtrain_count =  count_vect.transform(train_x)
    xvalid_count =  count_vect.transform(valid_x)

createTrainingAndValidation('Test')
createCountVectorizer('Test')
classifier = train_model(linear_model.LogisticRegression(), xtrain_count, train_y, xvalid_count)
predictions = getPredictions(classifier, xvalid_count)
```

I was using a DataFrame called `finalDF` with all labelled text. Since this model is giving me 0.68 accuracy I was going to test it on a subset of the DataFrame with an unknown label. This was not included in the training and testing phase. I saved the trained model as `bestClassifier`.

Now I got the subset of unknown text and tried to do the following:

```
count_vect = CountVectorizer()
count_vect.fit(unknownDf['Text'])
text = unknownDf['Text']
xvalid_count =  count_vect.transform(text)

bestClassifier.predict(xvalid_count)
```

`finalDF` has 800 rows while `unknownDf` has only 32 rows after what I do above.. How do I rectify this?

Comment: Can you post what the error is saying?

Comment: ValueError: X has 4386 features per sample; expecting 17744

Comment: I meant the full error log.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I see what's going on, In this peice of code:

```
def createCountVectorizer(column):
    global xtrain_count, xvalid_count
    # create a count vectorizer object 
    count_vect = CountVectorizer()
    count_vect.fit(finalDF[column])

    # transform the training and validation data using count vectorizer object
    xtrain_count =  count_vect.transform(train_x)
    xvalid_count =  count_vect.transform(valid_x)
```

You are declaring a `CountVectorizer()`, calling `fit` and then `transform`. What you need to do is, USE THE SAME `CountVectorizer()` to `transform` on `unknownDf['Text']`.

When you do this:

```
count_vect = CountVectorizer()
count_vect.fit(unknownDf['Text'])
text = unknownDf['Text']
xvalid_count =  count_vect.transform(text)
```

You are creating a brand new `CountVectorizer()`, that creates a new bag of words for `unknownDf['Text']`, when what you should be doing is, removing these two lines

```
count_vect = CountVectorizer()
count_vect.fit(unknownDf['Text'])
```

and let the existing `CountVectorizer()` which you `FIT` on `finalDF[column]`, use that to `transform` `unknownDf['Text']`.

Find a way to USE the `CountVectorizer()` in your `createCountVectorizer(column)` which you declared as `count_vect` to `transform` the `unknownDf['Text']`.